# Export Button grid array to Ms Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel, export-to-excel

Hi I have a small program that generates a grid using an array of buttons. when clicking on the buttons they change color. How can I export this layout into Ms Excel exactly how it is on the form is it even possible? I want the cells in Excel to represent the buttons

My program looks as follows:[image]

How I create my grid:

```
int col = 7;
int row = 4;
int count = 0;
Button[][] buttons;

public void placeRows()
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
            {
                createColumns(r);
            }
        }

        public void createColumns(int r)
        {
            int s = r * 25; //gap
            for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
            {
                buttons[r][c] = new Button();
                buttons[r][c].SetBounds(75 * c, s, 75, 25);
                buttons[r][c].Text = Convert.ToString(c);
                buttons[r][c].Click += new EventHandler(grid_Click);
                panel1.Controls.Add(buttons[r][c]);
            }
        }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            placeRows();
        }

 void grid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             Button button = sender as Button;

             if (count == 0)
             {
                 button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                 count++;
             }

             else if (count == 1)
             {
                 button.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                 count--;
             }
         }

private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             //have no idea how to start this

         }
```

Comment: By the lack of answers I'm guessing that this is very difficult to do or even impossible!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Excel COM component.

First you must add as a reference the Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library (in my case I'm using 12.0).

Below code contains simple class, that create new worksheet with data from array of buttons. If you want save your workspace, you should uncomment `app.SaveWorkspace(excelName);` in `Do` method.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace SimpleExcelExport
{
    class Export
    {
        public Export(bool defaultBackgroundIsWhite)
        {
            this.defaultBackgroundIsWhite = defaultBackgroundIsWhite;

            app = new Application();
            app.Visible = true;
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
            worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        }       

        public void Do(string excelName, System.Windows.Forms.Button[][] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= array.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= array[i].GetUpperBound(0); j++)
                {
                    AddData(i, j, array[i][j]);
                }
            }

            //app.SaveWorkspace(excelName);
        }            

        private void AddData(int row, int col, System.Windows.Forms.Button button)
        {
            if (button == null) return;
            row++;
            col++;
            Range range = worksheet.Cells[row, col];
            if (!defaultBackgroundIsWhite)
            range.Interior.Color = button.BackColor.ToArgb();
            else
                range.Interior.Color = button.BackColor.Name != "Control" ? button.BackColor.ToArgb() : System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb();
            range.NumberFormat = "";
            worksheet.Cells[row, col] = button.Text;
        }

        private Application app = null;
        private Workbook workbook = null;
        private Worksheet worksheet = null;
        private Range workSheet_range = null;
        private bool defaultBackgroundIsWhite;
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Export ep = new Export(true);
    ep.Do("test.xsl", buttons);
}
```

Comment: the excel file is created correctly but this line  range.Interior.Color = button.BackColor.Name != "Control" ? button.BackColor.ToArgb() : System.Drawing.Color.White.ToArgb(); throws an exception after the export is done it says NullReferenceExceptionunhundled

Comment: @Tacit could you check which element is null?

Comment: button.BackColor.Name and button.BackColor.ToArgb()

Comment: @Tacit check `AddData` method again, I added there following condition: `if (button == null) return;`, in the first line.

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is to create some array with data-ready-to-use so you can do 2 things:

1. Generate your buttons based on that array.
2. Export this array to MS Excel like [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

So drop out that line

```
panel1.Controls.Add(buttons[r][c]);
```

and populate your array with data.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into that

Comment: How can I drop that line out. If I do that my grid wont show on the form. panel1 is holding the grid

Comment: @Tacit You have to populate new Array/List with your data. After this Use this Array/List to create your buttons. But keep this Array/List  like a global variable so u can export data to MS Excel.